Please help, Trying to understand what this statement is saying
Our company's staff retention report says the following:

Once a person is identified as affected, their home department and Client Service Manager work with the employee to identify potential employment opportunities within this organization
In fiscal year 2019-2020, nine (9) individuals were identified as “affected employees” under the Staff Retention Policy, as follows:

Number of positions affected by lay-off or voluntary separation – 9
Number of affected employees – 9
Number of employees laid-off – 2
Number subject to voluntary separation – 0
Number of affected employees who chose to exercise a lay-off option rather than seeking retraining or an alternate position – 2
Retraining and redeployment options identified for employees subject to lay-off  – 5
Confirmation that all reasonable options to retain the employees were explored –
Yes


I am trying to understand who the 5 training and redeployment options were identified for:

Is it the 2 employees who were laid off or all the 9 affected employees?

English is not my first language so any help understanding this will be appreciated.

You want to know if the 5 are 2 or 9? Aren't they 5 ... 5 out of the 9?

This department was required to reduce its size by 9 positions.
2 employees were laid off involuntarily. No employees quit voluntarily.
The remaining 7 were given the choice of either being laid off or being transferred to another department (this is "redeployment"). 2 of them chose the lay-off option, the other 5 chose "retraining and redeployment".
